# Return object of functions with argument types of incoming function argument values

Tags: typescript, dynamic-typing

I'd like to have function, let's call it `DummyService` that would accept some `definition` object as argument and return bunch of functions in a way that arguments of those returned functions can only accept argument values that has been passed to `DummyService` as an argument. See the code example bellow. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks a lot in advance.

````js
type Definition = {
    id: string;
    steps: Array<{key: string, callback?: () => void}>
};

const DummyService = (definition: Definition) => {
    return { 
        dummyFn: (step: {key: any}) => { // I need to figure out the type that would allow to pass only certain values that has been passed in `steps` array of `definition`
            console.log(step);
        }
    };
};

const DummyComponent1 = () => {
    const definition = {
        id: "testId1",
        steps: [
            {  key: "key1"},
            {  key: "key2"},
        ],
    };

    const { dummyFn } = DummyService(definition);
    const handler = () => dummyFn({ key: "key1dsfasd" }); // I want this to be invalid - valid key values should be only "key1" or "key2"

    return <div onClick={handler}>test</div>;
}

const DummyComponent2 = () => {
    const definition = {
        id: "testId2",
        steps: [
            {  key: "key3"},
            {  key: "key4"},
        ],
    };

    const { dummyFn } = DummyService(definition);
    const handler = () => dummyFn({ key: "key3" }); // This should be valid - valid key values should be only "key2" or "key4"

    return <div onClick={handler}>test</div>;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

We need to make `Definition` an generic that depends on the array of steps.

The tricky, messy part here is dealing with strings like `"key1"` and `"key2"` as their literal values instead of just type `string`.  In order to do that, we must add `as const` after the `definition`

```
const definition = {/*...*/} as const;
```

This interprets the values as literal strings, but it also makes everything in the definition `readonly`.  So we need to add a bunch of `readonly` when defining the types for `Definition` and `DummyService` or else we will get errors about assigning `readonly` to a mutable type.

A definition is defined like this:

```
type Definition<Steps extends readonly {key: string, callback?: () => void}[]> = {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly steps: Steps;
};
```

We say that our `Steps` `extends` an array, and we want it to be a specific tuple.

Our `DummyService` looks like this:

```
const DummyService = <Steps extends readonly {key: string, callback?: () => void}[]>(definition: Definition<Steps>) => {
    return { 
        dummyFn: (step: { key: Steps[number]['key'] }) => {
            console.log(step);
        }
    };
};
```

That type `Steps[number]['key']` gives us all valid step keys.  As a sidenote, I'm not sure why you want to pass your args like `({key: "key2"})` instead of just `("key2")`.

You now get all of the desired errors, and no errors when calling correctly.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/DmMrdW)